# HBase and PHP user guide?

Tags: php, hbase

I could not find a proper tutorial or guide on using PHP and Habse from the initial setup, lubraries to actually making it work with sample code. Are there any guides / tutorials as i want to use Hbase with my php codeignitor and mysql website for few really large read/write tables. I am brand new to hbase so starting fresh hence looking for a guide.

Comment: I googled around for a minute and found http://www.appaquet.com/2008/11/thrift-hbase-php.html.  No clue if that's any good or what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

[Integrate Hbase with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688449/integrate-hbase-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

There not a direct php to hbase api, you will actually use thrift to communicate or you can use their REST API (stargate).